# Common Promoted Links

Tags: inheritance, promoted-links

My Question is this:

If I create a promoted links list on a site and configure this list to specific images (stored in the sites picture library or equivalent) is it at all possible to then access and add this promoted links list on any sub sites created from the top level site?

This is simply a question as I am not sure whether this can be done or not, or is this a case of having to create new promoted links lists for each sub site?

Any answers or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify that you want to create a promoted link list with certain images (image library on root site) and would like this list to work on the subsite?

Comment: Hi, yeah that is exactly what I am after. The actual links can be changed but I was hoping for a consistent look and easy to produce promoted links template in effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOTB not possible.

To generally describe, your requirement would be to show list items from a parent site in the way the built-in Promoted Links do display. Because we can only *query* list items from a parent site by using `Content Query Web Part`, the Promoted Link's way of displaying the links is not available.

If you are open for customization, you may achieve the same results by using the above mentioned CWQP with a custom display template. CQWP uses a selected display template which determines the way the queried list items are shown, and this could be such that mimics the Promoted Link's display template. However, due to the functionality of the Promoted Links (e.g. the animation, etc.), building it from a scratch demands some fairly advanced front-end customization skills.

Comment: Hi Moe, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think that is an option for me in my current situation. Its good to know that it isn't possible however as I can start to look for other options. Thanks for your time and answer! :)